# JQuery Validation Plugin - Validating fields if user selects either radio button.

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

I am using the jQuery validation plugin on my form.

The user can choose from the radio buttons Option1, Option2 or Option3. Depending on the selection, a div is shown where they enter their shipping address. The validation works perfectly requiring Option3 be checked before validating the shipping address.

```
ShipToAddress1: {
  required: "#Option3:checked"
},
```

I also have second radio button that can also show the hidden shipping address.

This is where I am running into a problem. How can I validate the shipping address if the user either selects Option3 or if they select Option2?

I have seen plenty of examples using just requirements, but nothing with an "or" option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've not tested this, but assuming that property accepts any basic selector then you should be able to split them with a comma: `required: "#Option2:checked, #Option3:checked"`

Comment: That did it. Thank you, I think I was over-thinking the solution.

Comment: Glad to help. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that property accepts any basic selector then you should be able to split them with a comma:

```
ShipToAddress1: {
    required: "#Option2:checked, #Option3:checked" 
}
```